# Interpreting meter values of extent using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, extents, scale, map-unit

I am using ArcGIS Pro application to create a map and add a single polygon feature class onto the map.

As shown below, I use bold polyline to outline the boundary of the polygon and click "zoom to layer" to make sure the current display extent fit the polygon well.

Then I check the current visible extent and I get the set of the four meter values.

[image]

Then I try to customize the extent by choosing the polygon feature class and the extent value looks totally different. What I expect is to see very similar meter values there.

[image]

What does each representation of extent mean so that I can understand the difference seen here?

Comment: It looks like your map and data are in different coordinate systems, please include the details of the maps spatial reference and the feature class' spatial reference. Please note that *before* you add a feature and save a shapefile extent is not yet set (you could undo) and should automatically update when you save.

Comment: If you "Zoom to" the farm Lot layer, does it scale to a larger area? It could be the shapefile has a larger extent than you are using and it is reporting on features (existing or NULL) hence why the extents are so different.

Comment: @KeaganAllan No, the layer only include this polygon feature so I zoom to layer and see a map view perfectly bounding this polygon

Comment: @MichaelStimson I try to align the coordinate system for both map and feature class but the meter values are still different as shown.

Comment: I don't even find a good explanation about extent values from online. Could someone can provide a reference on interpreting the meter values set in extent and what kind of projection/spatial reference info it contained? Much appreciated.